Issues with CI/CD Setup on Azure with VM, ACR, and GitHub (Docker Compose + Traefik Reverse Proxy)
I'm setting up a CI/CD pipeline using Azure DevOps, a Virtual Machine (VM) on Azure, and Azure Container Registry (ACR). My project uses Docker Compose and Traefik as a reverse proxy. Due to specific requirements, I'm using a VM instead of a managed service.
However, I'm encountering an issue where my VM isn't pulling images from ACR correctly. It seems like there might be a problem with the image tags or the way the images are being referenced.
Here’s the error I’m receiving:
2024-08-14T10:40:44.7501592Z ##[error]Pulling ai_backend (***/ai_backend:latest)...

2024-08-14T10:40:44.9192452Z ##[error]manifest for ***/ai_backend:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by "latest" is not found

2024-08-14T10:40:45.0897108Z ##[section]Finishing: SSH

It looks like the 'latest' tag might not be found, but I'm not sure if this is a configuration issue with the VM, ACR, or the CI/CD pipeline itself.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide guidance on what might be going wrong?
Below are the relevant files:

azure-pipelines.yml
docker-compose.yml

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Please note that my project is based on the Full-Stack FastAPI Template available on GitHub.
azure-pipelines.yml:
trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'
  group: 'XXXXXXXXXXX'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and deploy stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildAndDeploy
    displayName: Build and Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'XXXXXXXXXXX (XXXXXXXXXXX)'
        scriptType: bash
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          az acr login --name markingsystemreg

    - task: Docker@2
      inputs:
        command: login
        containerRegistry: 'markingsystemreg'

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and Push ai_backend image
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        dockerfile: 'ai_backend/Dockerfile'
        repository: 'markingsystemreg.azurecr.io/ai_backend'
        tags: |
          $(Build.BuildId)
          latest

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and Push backend image
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        dockerfile: 'backend/Dockerfile'
        repository: 'markingsystemreg.azurecr.io/backend'
        tags: |
          $(Build.BuildId)
          latest

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and Push frontend image
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        dockerfile: 'frontend/Dockerfile'
        repository: 'markingsystemreg.azurecr.io/frontend'
        tags: |
          $(Build.BuildId)
          latest

    - task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
      inputs:
        sshEndpoint: 'my-ssh-connection'
        sourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        targetFolder: '/home/XXXXXXXXXXX/deploy'
        cleanTargetFolder: true

    - task: SSH@0
      inputs:
        sshEndpoint: 'my-ssh-connection'
        runOptions: inline
        inline: |
          clientId="XXXXXXXXXXX"
          clientSecret="XXXXXXXXXXX"
          tenantId="XXXXXXXXXXX"

          # Install Azure CLI
          curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
          az --version

          # Login to Azure
          az login --service-principal -u $clientId -p $clientSecret --tenant $tenantId
          az acr login --name markingsystemreg

          # Get the latest tag from the repository
          LATEST_TAG=$(az acr repository show-tags --name markingsystemreg --repository markingsystemreg.azurecr.io/ai_backend --output tsv --orderby time_desc --top 1)
          
          # Navigate to the deployment directory
          cd /home/XXXXXXXXXXX/deploy

          # Install Docker Compose
          sudo curl -sL "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.29.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
          sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
          docker-compose --version

          # Update the docker-compose.yml to use the correct tag
          sed -i "s/:latest/:$LATEST_TAG/" docker-compose.yml

    - task: SSH@0
      inputs:
        sshEndpoint: 'my-ssh-connection'
        runOptions: inline
        inline: |
          az acr login --name markingsystemreg
          cd /home/AssessmentProjectVMUser/deploy
          docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d

docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.13-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - default
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "rabbitmqctl status"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  ai_backend:
    image: markingsystemreg.azurecr.io/ai_backend:${TAG:-latest}
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - PYTHONPATH=/app/ai_backend
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "rabbitmq:5672", "--timeout=60", "--", "uvicorn", "api:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "85"]
    networks:
      - default

  pdf_consumer:
    build:
      context: ./ai_backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: pdf_consumer
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - PYTHONPATH=/app/ai_backend
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "rabbitmq:5672", "--timeout=60", "--", "python", "RMQ/consumers/pdf_process_consumer.py"]
    networks:
      - default

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    networks:
      - traefik-public
      - default
    environment:
      - ADMINER_DESIGN=pepa-linha-dark
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
      - traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-adminer-http.rule=Host(`adminer.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-adminer-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-adminer-http.middlewares=https-redirect
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-adminer-https.rule=Host(`adminer.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-adminer-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-adminer-https.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-adminer-https.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-adminer.loadbalancer.server.port=8080

  backend:
    image: markingsystemreg.azurecr.io/backend:${TAG:-latest}
    restart: always
    networks:
      - traefik-public
      - default
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - DOMAIN=${DOMAIN}
      - ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT}
      - BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS=${BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS}
      - SECRET_KEY=${SECRET_KEY?Variable not set}
      - FIRST_SUPERUSER=${FIRST_SUPERUSER?Variable not set}
      - FIRST_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=${FIRST_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD?Variable not set}
      - USERS_OPEN_REGISTRATION=${USERS_OPEN_REGISTRATION}
      - SMTP_HOST=${SMTP_HOST}
      - SMTP_USER=${SMTP_USER}
      - SMTP_PASSWORD=${SMTP_PASSWORD}
      - EMAILS_FROM_EMAIL=${EMAILS_FROM_EMAIL}
      - AZURE_SQL_SERVER=${AZURE_SQL_SERVER}
      - AZURE_SQL_PORT=${AZURE_SQL_PORT}
      - AZURE_SQL_DATABASE=${AZURE_SQL_DATABASE}
      - AZURE_SQL_USERNAME=${AZURE_SQL_USERNAME}
      - AZURE_SQL_PASSWORD=${AZURE_SQL_PASSWORD}
      - AZURE_SQL_DRIVER=${AZURE_SQL_DRIVER}
      - AZURE_SQL_ENCRYPT=${AZURE_SQL_ENCRYPT}
      - AZURE_SQL_TRUST_CERTIFICATE=${AZURE_SQL_TRUST_CERTIFICATE}
      - TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT}
      - SENTRY_DSN=${SENTRY_DSN}
    build:
      context: ./backend
      args:
        INSTALL_DEV: ${INSTALL_DEV-false}
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
      - traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public
      - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend.loadbalancer.server.port=80
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-http.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`, `www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`) && PathPrefix(`/api`, `/docs`, `/redoc`)
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-https.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`, `www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`) && PathPrefix(`/api`, `/docs`, `/redoc`)
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-https.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-https.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-http.middlewares=https-redirect,${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-backend-https.middlewares=${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect

  frontend:
    image: markingsystemreg.azurecr.io/frontend:${TAG:-latest}
    restart: always
    networks:
      - traefik-public
      - default
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      args:
        - VITE_API_URL=https://${DOMAIN?Variable not set}
        - NODE_ENV=production
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=traefik-public
      - traefik.constraint-label=traefik-public
      - traefik.http.services.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend.loadbalancer.server.port=80
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-http.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`, `www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-https.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`, `www.${DOMAIN?Variable not set}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-https.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-https.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-https.tls.certresolver=le
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect.redirectregex.regex=^http(s)?://www.(${DOMAIN?Variable not set})/(.*)
      - traefik.http.middlewares.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect.redirectregex.replacement=http$${1}://${DOMAIN?Variable not set}/$${3}
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-https.middlewares=${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect
      - traefik.http.routers.${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-frontend-http.middlewares=https-redirect,${STACK_NAME?Variable not set}-www-redirect

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true


Azure DevOps - Pipeline Logs - SS
Azure Container Registry - Tags for ai_backend images.
As you can see from the screenshot, when I initially listed the available images, it displayed ones that were created 26 hours ago.
Next, I manually pulled the ai_backend Docker image, which had actually been updated two hours ago with Azure DevOps. Once manual pull process finished, I listed images again and it showed as being created two hours ago. This suggests that I may not be pulling the images properly.
Additionally, even when I tried running docker-compose manually on the VM, I still encountered the same error.
